# How to send mysql data to email after submitting the form by customer?

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

After customer filling the form, the form data will be send to mysql, and an email will sent to me with only the last form data that customer submitted. All is working, but only **the problem is in the email "mysql data" is not going as inline text**. So, how to do this? I am doing in PHP. I have just two weeks experience on PHP. Sample code is given below. Please help.

```
<?php


define('DB_NAME', 'sandi565_form11');
define('DB_USER', '********');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '********');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

$link = mysql_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

//Start Posting the data in Mysql database from Form Input

$value = $_POST['input1'];
$value2 = $_POST['MAmount'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO demo (input1, MAmount) VALUES ('$value', '$value2')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

}

//start print the database on form processing page

$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>ID:</th> <td>".$info['ID'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Input1:</th> <td>".$info['input1'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>MAmount:</th> <td>".$info['MAmount'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 

mysql_close();


//end print the database on form processing page

//start emailing the data


date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
//include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

//$body             = preg_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "ssl://stevie.********.org"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "stevie.********.org";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "contact@********.com";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "********";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('contact@********.com', 'HAL');

//$mail->AddReplyTo("user2@gmail.com', 'First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "Halmira 469";
//$body             = "gdssdh";

//THE PROBLEM IS HERE WHEN I WANT TO SEND THE DATA AS BODY TO EMAIL FROM MYSQL IT IS NOT WORKING. SHOWING ERROR MESSAGE BODY EMPTY.

$Body = "Print the data"; @MYSQL_CONNECT("localhost","********","********");
@mysql_select_db("sandi565_form11");
$query["SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"];
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($query);


//$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "********@gmail.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "user2");

//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
//$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
//end email the data

?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: If this is on the internet, you're living on borrowed time. This has a gigantic [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/php) in it.

Answer (score 0):

Wow is it even supposed to work?

```
$Body = "Print the data"; @MYSQL_CONNECT("localhost","********","********");
@mysql_select_db("sandi565_form11");
$query["SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"];
$result = @MYSQL_QUERY($query);
```

Wrong Function names (Capital letters) and then query is not assigned to string correctly

Try

```
$Body = "Print the data"; mysql_connect("localhost","********","********");
@mysql_select_db("sandi565_form11");
$query="SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: And even with those fixes, that data is not being fetched anywhere and hence not being added to email body

Comment: I am new in PHP. Please can you explain this "query is not assigned to string correctly". And also "capital letters" are you suggest mysql_query.

Comment: Hello Hanky Panky, I have tried your suggestion but it is still showing that - Mailer Error () Message body empty.

Comment: Yes. To assign a string to a variable you have to try like $query="testing testing testing";  whereas you had $query["stringstringstring"]. that was wrong. Also PHP functions are case sensitive, MYSQL_QUERY does not mean same as mysql_query

Comment: That is because even when the query is running, you are not fetching any data from its result and hence no assignment to body. I would suggest rewritting this code, simplify and secure it, rather than trying to find any temporary fixes

Comment: Hello Hanky Panky, just I have rewritten the code -               $body                = 'Print the data';
mysql_connect("localhost","*******","*******");
@mysql_select_db("sandi565_form11");
$query["SELECT * FROM demo ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"];
$result = mysql_query($query);$body;                                But now only Print the data is going and not the database. What I should do? Thanks for your quick support.